# Programmatically Extracting Sprites

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, emulation, programmatically-created

I'd like to recreate one of my favorite NES (Nintendo Entertainment System) games using Pygame. Is there a way that I can programmatically extract sprites from say an NES emulator that I can then use in my project as bitmaps? This is a lesser known game so as far as I know there are no sprite sheets already available as there would be for say a game like Super Mario. Thanks.

Comment: Why are people voting down? At least tell me what's wrong with my question. It's legitimate and I'm doing it to learn Pygame. I'm not trying to make any money.

Comment: NES emulatr should have own forum - maybe ask on this forum. They should know how to get images from NES game.

Comment: @furas it's really like saying python developers should go to python forums not here on STO. why we need stackoverflow then?

Comment: @LabhamJain I don't mean `python forum` but `nes forums` or `game forums`. Stackoverflow has also portal for [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) which might be better place for question about games. Frankly, I never saw any question about NES on this portal and I expected that OP may have problem to get any answer here. And his may need to visit portals more specialized for NES. People on portals for NES may have better idea how to extract resources from NES games. BTW: I found also forum [NesDev](https://forums.nesdev.org/) and [NES](https://www.reddit.com/r/nes/) on Reddit

Comment: I agree, however this still a python surrounded question it can be asked here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you to use one of the utilities available [here](http://www.zophar.net/utilities/nesgraph.html). For instance, [Graphics Extractor and Inserter](http://www.zophar.net/utilities/nesgraph/graphics-extractor-and-inserter.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Exactly what I was looking for. Very cool utilities. Thanks again!